# Can I add In-App Purchases to free android game

Tags: in-app-purchase, game-development

I'm new to game development and I'm developing my 1st game in unity. I want to publish my game to the Google Play Store and App Store for free without any In-App purchases, but after some updates can I add In-App purchases to my game. I want to add In-App purchases after some time because at that time I don't have too much knowledge about game development and especially C#.

Comment: I've never worked with in-app purchases, so to be safe, I'll write a comment instead of an answer. I don't think there is any problem. When you add the in app purchase to the app you also add it to the platform where you sell the app and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

According to a Unity3D docs, that should be possible.

I recommend to read a manual about integrating In-App Purchases (unity docs) or check a Unity's official tutorial (https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/unity-iap) about IAP :)